# Comparison of two different database and fetching the matched records from the two database tables

Tags: java, oracle

Hi All I need help is understanding the appropriate approach. Actually my requirement is to compare two different database tables and fetched the matched records from those tables to a new one, the column names are different for those two database tables.

Comment: if column names are diff , how do you know which column to be compared with which one ???

Comment: maybe you can show us how you create the queries on each database? have you already tried to insert/update the compared data into your third database?

Comment: An example would be helpful that shows what kind of database technology your ar using. Since you picked oracle as a tag you might talk about an Oracle sql database. For the diff it's important to no the column types to be compared. And then It's important what kind of comparison you'd like to see - equality - phonetic similarity - same time range? Please be more specific with your question.

Comment: Looks like a simple `SELECT` or `SELECT INTO`/`INSERT FROM (SELECT)`. Nothing special, really.

Comment: What you want is to select lines from first table and lines from second table where data in a colmun from 1st table is equal to another colmun from 2nd table? Oh wait, I've almost written proper SQL ^^

Comment: Hi all, I understand the question is not quite clear.Let me tell you, column names are different but records in the respective columns are  similar.
 I need to create a automation so that on one click all the operation are done starts with fetching -comparison-ends with inserting in new table.
let me Tell my Idea, Is it feasible  to use apache poi package for cells comparison of data.  
 Like Column Emp_No of T-1 is compared with Column Worker_No of T-2.   @ WolfgangFahl